# rubyで1回目は必ず実行するwhile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
while false
  puts 1
end
```

このような条件でも1回は必ず実行するwhileはrubyでは用意されていないでしょうか

Comment: [Is there a "do ... while" loop in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136793/is-there-a-do-while-loop-in-ruby)

Answer (score 3):

既出ですがbegin節とwhile修飾子(後置while)を組み合わせるとできます。

```
begin
  puts 1
end while false
```

が。[Ruby Style Guideではこの記法は推奨されていません](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/blob/master/README.md#loop-with-break)。かわりに`loop/break`の組み合わせを使ってください。

```
loop do
  puts 1
  break unless false
end
```

while修飾子はbegin節と組み合わせるか否かで動作が異なりますので、誤解によるバグの種となります。

```
puts 1 while false #何もしない

begin; puts 1; end while false #puts 1が呼ばれる
```

Answer (score 1):

```
begin
  puts 1
end while false
```

でどうでしょうか。